# Filter dataframe index on multiple conditions

Tags: pandas, filter

In [pandas.DataFrame.filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) is there a way to  use the parameters "like" or "regex" so they support an OR condition.  for example:

```
df.filter(like='bbi', axis=1)
```

would filter on columns with `bbi` in their name, but how would I filter on columns containing `'bbi'` OR `'abc'` ?

A few options that fail:

```
df.filter(like='bbi' or 'abc', axis=1) 

df.filter(like=('bbi' or 'abc'), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would do the below:

Setup:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,20,20).reshape(5,4),
                          columns=['abcd','bcde','efgh','bbia'])
print(df)
```

---

```
   abcd  bcde  efgh  bbia
0    10    17     2     7
1     7    12    18     9
2    17     7    11    17
3    14     4     2     9
4    15    10    12    11
```

Solution:

Using `df.filter`:

```
df.filter(regex=r'(abc|bbi)')
```

---

```
   abcd  bbia
0    10     7
1     7     9
2    17    17
3    14     9
4    15    11
```

Answer (score 3):

Not familiar with the `filter` command. But you could achieve what you want like this I think:

```
df[(df['column'].str.contains('bbi', case=False)) | (df['column'].str.contains('abc', case=False))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find the attached screenshot.[image: enter image description here[![enter image description here]

Regex search is slower. So we keep `regex=False`.

Hope this helps.Thank you.