# Remove groups from pandas where {condition}

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have dataframe like this:

```
+---+--------------------------------------+-----------+
|   |              envelopeid              |  message  |
+---+--------------------------------------+-----------+
| 1 | d55edb65-dc77-41d0-bb53-43cf01376a04 | CMN.00002 |
| 2 | d55edb65-dc77-41d0-bb53-43cf01376a04 | CMN.00004 |
| 3 | d55edb65-dc77-41d0-bb53-43cf01376a04 | CMN.11001 |
| 4 | 5cb72b9c-adb8-4e1c-9296-db2080cb3b6d | CMN.00002 |
| 5 | 5cb72b9c-adb8-4e1c-9296-db2080cb3b6d | CMN.00001 |
| 6 | f4260b99-6579-4607-bfae-f601cc13ff0c | CMN.00202 |
| 7 | 8f673ae3-0293-4aca-ad6b-572f138515e6 | CMN.00002 |
| 8 | fee98470-aa8f-4ec5-8bcd-1683f85727c2 | TKP.00001 |
| 9 | 88926399-3697-4e15-8d25-6cb37a1d250e | CMN.00002 |
| 10| 88926399-3697-4e15-8d25-6cb37a1d250e | CMN.00004 |
+---+--------------------------------------+-----------+
```

I've grouped it with `grouped = df.groupby('envelopeid')`
And I need to remove all groups from the dataframe and stay only that groups that have messages (CMN.00002) or (CMN.00002 and CMN.00004) only.
Desired dataframe:

```
+---+--------------------------------------+-----------+
|   |              envelopeid              |  message  |
+---+--------------------------------------+-----------+
| 7 | 8f673ae3-0293-4aca-ad6b-572f138515e6 | CMN.00002 |
| 9 | 88926399-3697-4e15-8d25-6cb37a1d250e | CMN.00002 |
| 10| 88926399-3697-4e15-8d25-6cb37a1d250e | CMN.00004 |
+---+--------------------------------------+-----------+
```

tried

```
(grouped.message.transform(lambda x: x.eq('CMN.00001').any() or (x.eq('CMN.00002').any() and x.ne('CMN.00002' or 'CMN.00004').any()) or x.ne('CMN.00002').all()))
```

but it is not working properly

Comment: You can use regex as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58752330/filter-dataframe-index-on-multiple-conditions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
outdf = df.groupby('envelopeid').filter(lambda x: tuple(x.message)== ('CMN.00002',) or tuple(x.message)== ('CMN.00002','CMN.00004'))
```

So i figured it up.
resulting dataframe will got only groups that have only CMN.00002 message or CMN.00002 and CMN.00004. This is what I need.
I used filter instead of transform.

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
grouped = df.loc[df['message'].isin(['CMN.00002', 'CMN.00002', 'CMN.00004'])].groupby('envelopeid')
```

Comment: It shows empty group for me
may be you meant 
grouped = df.loc[df['message'].isin(['CMN.00002', 'CMN.00002', 'CMN.00004'])].groupby('envelopeid')

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `df[df.message== 'CMN.00002']`

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.