# Pandas filter for column names using multiple like criteria

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I would like to use the simplicity of pandas dataframe filter but using multiple `LIKE` criteria. I have many columns in a dataframe that I would like to organize the column headers into different lists.

For example - any column titles containing "time".

```
df.filter(like='time',axis=1)``
```

And then any columns containing either "mins" or "secs". But how do I allow for multiple criteria in this simple, clean statement? I've tried many iterations of something like this, is there a way to do so or this statement does not allow for it? If not, other simple, clean approaches are welcome!

```
df.filter(like=('mins','secs'),axis=1)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter dataframe index on multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58752330/filter-dataframe-index-on-multiple-conditions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `like`.  `like` is used to **keep labels for which `like in label == True`.**

You instead want [DataFrame.filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) `regex` type filtering, joining your substrings with `|`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=1, columns=['foo', 'bar', 'foobar', 'bazz'], index=[0])

df.filter(regex='foo|bar')
#   foo  bar  foobar
#0    1    1       1
```

---

If you want the filtering to be "not like", I find it easier to use a list comprehension to find the labels to keep. Here we exclude any labels that contain either `'foo'` or `'bar'`

```
cols = [label for label in df.columns if not any(x in label for x in ['foo', 'bar'])]

df[cols]
#   bazz
#0     1
```

Comment: thank you! and if I wanted ```not like``` is that straightforward for this approach?

Comment: @paranormaldist I find `regex` to be very complicated to create matches that **don't** contain X or Y...  I think in that case you're better off with a simple list comprehension, but maybe some regex gods will disagree

Comment: For inverse I would also consider, `df.loc[:,~df.columns.str.contains('foo|bar')]` but yes, I agree to - when not required, dont use regex :)